# Is there a way to import the year from datetime directly?

Tags: python

There's a question I've been wondering about for the datetime module as if there's a way to import the year function within the same line like:

> from datetime.date.today import year

or something along the lines... or it is not possible and I would have to import date then extract the year to from the today function.

Comment: Well the `year` is not a function nor it is a `class` it is `Data descriptor` just check `help(date.today())`.

Comment: You can't... but you can get the current year in two ways(maybe more): `print(datetime.datetime.now().year)` and `print(datetime.datetime.today().year)`

Comment: this might sound pretty dumb but I had no idea about that, so I can't exactly call the year class directly but i can assign it to a variable to make it easier to work with? I also know you can get the year using the now func but what is the difference between the two

Comment: @Jay_gov It's not dump. You just need to know the `year` is not a class. It simply does not exist until you run `date.today()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably to easiest way to do it:

```
from datetime import date
print(date.today().year)
```

the "today" function builds a datetime object for you using the current unix time, so you can't import the year without instantiating a new datetime object this way to parse the unix timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

You can only import an `object (class, function or a constant)` or a `module` or a `package` in python.

The `year` is an integer data part of return value of `today()` function so it cannot be imported.